# What bodies exist to foster cooperation amongst transnational corporations?

Tags: corporations

Sometimes competing corporations meet and discuss solutions to common problems and create trade organizations or political lobby groups. Sometimes countries with similar economic interests form organisations (e.g. OPEC).

Are there examples for similar associations, unions, organisations, yearly forums etc. for transnational corporations?

Comment: Yes. It's called playing golf :)

Answer (score -1):

Most of the big political lobby groups are made up of transnational companies. Take PhRMA(Pharmaceutical Research and Manufacturers of America) which is the group of the big pharma companies.

While PhRMA has America in it's name, it includes for example Sanofi which is headquarterd in Paris. All of the Big Pharma companies are essentially transnational.

Comment: Hm. Technically correct, but that's because most big Pharma companis ARE transnational. The grouping is due to their professional nature, not their transnational nature. You can say the same thing about semiconductor or electronics trade groups and lobbies.

Comment: @DVK: I don't think it makes sense to speak about them grouping because of their *nature*. Companies group to succeed at pushing their interests and making money.

Comment: the point is, PhRMA membership isn't selected because of their transnational nature but because of their industry